# How can I obtain a string that display the Hex value of a byte?

Tags: c++, string, byte, tostring

I'm new to C++ and I have a simple and stupid issue and I hope someone can help me!
I have a byte, for example:

```
uint8_t MyByte = 0x0C;
```

and I want to convert it into a string corresponding to the hexadecimal MyByte value, in this case **"0C"**.
If I try:

```
std::string MyString = std::to_string(MyByte);
```

I will obtain: MyString = **"12"**; I want to obtain MyString = **"0C"** instead, that is the corresponding hex value.
Is it possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I know there is a similar question on the link provided, but it is not right form me. In fact, if I try:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << MyByte;
std::string MyString( stream.str() );
```

MyString doesn't shows me as expected.

I just tryied this solution, it seems it's working:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << (int)MyByte; // cast needed
std::string MyString( stream.str() );
std::transform(strBcc.begin(), strBcc.end(),strBcc.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::ostringstream` and `std::hex`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::hex << (int)MyByte;
```

To obtain the string use

```
std::string MyString = oss.str();
```

Comment: Thanks. In this way, I obtain MyString = "0c". Is there a way to obtain "0C" instead?